# Issue when using Orchard Web matrix module in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have implemented Nwazet commerce module & related functionality inside the Web matrix. now there are many changes required in implementation so need to work out in the visual studio. Now in visual studio i have just copied my implemented module of Web matrix and paste it in visual studio modules also applied DB related changes as well with the theme related changes also but it causes too many issues at the time of loading. also try to convert project in visual studio with upper ribbon available in Web Matrix with the option of Visual Studio Launch but it also gives error related to visual studio 2010 shell.

Comment: is there any proper way to do this particular job ?

Comment: Actually when i try to run at admin side all things runs fine. Also module & related content also loads properly but when try to load front end "Memory Out of Exception" related error occurs, as well several issues related to shape is also occurs.

Comment: Shape related issue : An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
in the file : ShapeAttributeBindingStrategy.cs

Comment: If you're going to do module development, you need to work from the source code version, not the executable zip.